# In Grails passing a taglib return value into a view via a g:set

Tags: grails, view, taglib

I'm using grail 2.3.3 and I'm trying to assign an HTML value to the return value of a customized tagLib. I have tried a number of approaches without success.

What is happening is that the correct output is being displayed on the web page (so the the logic of the tagLib is okay) but the single value I need is not being passed to the to 'var' organId.

Having checked out various earlier posts here are the things that I've tired so far in the view gsp file:

```
       <g:returnLoginInfo loginId="${loginId}" fieldName="organId">
            <g:set var="organId" value="${0}" scope="flash" />
        </g:returnLoginInfo>
```

I've also tried value="${it}" being the default it argument that references the value passed from the tagLib. In the tagLib I've tried both returning the single value via an "out << " as well as trying a return having added the line:

```
    static returnObjectForTags = ['returnLoginInfo']
```

which ensures that the tagLib can return values as opposed to sending text directly the be displayed.

The other approach within the view gsp file has been:

```
  <g:set var="organId" value="${bind.returnLoginInfo(loginId="${loginId}" fieldName="organId")}"/>
```

I would welcome any suggestions.

Here is the tagLib:

```
package homevu1

class ReturnLoginInfoTagLib {
//static defaultEncodeAs = 'html'
static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']

//static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: 'raw']

//static returnObjectForTags = ['returnLoginInfo'] // now expects a return statement rather than an out at the end

def returnLoginInfo = {attrs, body->
    def loginId = attrs["loginId"]
    def fieldName= attrs["fieldName"]

    def tagName = "returnLoginInfo"
    log.debug(" $tagName START loginId: $loginId fieldName: $fieldName")

    def secUserInstance = SecUser.get(loginId)
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser: $secUserInstance")
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser id: $secUserInstance.id")
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser role: $secUserInstance.role")
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser organId: $secUserInstance.organId")

    def returnValue

    if (fieldName == "organId")
    {
        def organisationInstance= OrganisationShr.findByName(secUserInstance.organId)
        returnValue = organisationInstance.id   
    }


    log.debug(" $tagName returnValue: $returnValue")
    //return returnValue
    out << body(returnValue)
} // end returnLoginInfo
```

As suggested by Jacob below I've tried two ways to invoke this tagLib from  the view:

```
        <g:set var="organId" value="${g.returnLoginInfo(loginId:"${loginId}", fieldName:"organId")}" />
```

and

```
<g:returnLoginInfo loginId="${loginId}" fieldName="organId">
        <g:set var="organId" value="${it}" />
    </g:returnLoginInfo>
```

Not too sure how I should be coding the return statement for the first method?

Using a filter - UPDATE 2:

Here is the service (not sure if I've got the syntax of the return value correct):

```
package homevu1

class HvLoginDetailsService {

def springSecurityService

def myLoginDetails() {

    def serviceName = "myLoginDetails"
    def returnValue = 0

    log.debug(" $serviceName hello world: $returnValue")

    return 'hello'
} // end returnLoginInfo

} // HvLoginDetailsService
```

Here is the filter definition:

```
package homevu1

  class HomeVuFiltersController {

    def HvLoginDetailsService

    def filters = {
        loginFilters(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {

            }
            after = { Map model ->
                model.currentLoginDetails = HvLoginDetailsService.myLoginDetails()
            }

    }
  }
  } //eof controller
```

Finally, I'm calling this in a html web page :

either through the filter:

```
            <p> ${currentLoginDetails}</p>
```

This displays the page but fails to display this return value "hello" - which I believe is because it is unable to resolve the filter and simply assumes currentLoginDetails is an undefined value in html.

Or directly from the service:

```
            <p> ${grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("hvLoginDetailsService").myLoginDetails()}</p>
```

This fails with an error:

> No bean named 'HvLoginDetailsService' is defined

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to set a value from a taglib (tested with Grails 2.5.0), you must let your TagLib use the out variable, like this:

```
class DemoTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']

    def stackOverflowExample = { attrs ->
        out << "This is your value ${attrs.value}"
    }
}
```

And you can in your gsp use it like this (both ways work)

```
<g:set var="organId" value="${g.stackOverflowExample(value:'Hello Grails')}" />
<h1>organId = ${organId}</h1>
<h1>organId2 = ${g.stackOverflowExample(value:'Hi Grails')}</h1>
```

To get it to work like in your first example, you can do something along the lines of this, referencing the body parameter in your taglib:

```
def anotherExample = { attrs, body ->
    out << body('My new return value')
}
```

And using it in the gsp:

```
<g:anotherExample>
    <g:set var="myVariable" value="${it}" />
    <h2>Hey: ${myVariable}</h2>
</g:anotherExample>
```

UPDATE:

With your taglib defined as this:

```
def returnLoginInfo = {attrs, body->
    def loginId = attrs["loginId"]
    def fieldName= attrs["fieldName"]

    def tagName = "returnLoginInfo"
    log.debug(" $tagName START loginId: $loginId fieldName: $fieldName")

    /*
    def secUserInstance = SecUser.get(loginId)
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser: $secUserInstance")
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser id: $secUserInstance.id")
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser role: $secUserInstance.role")
    log.debug(" $tagName secUser organId: $secUserInstance.organId")
    */
    def returnValue = 10

    if (fieldName == "organId")
    {
//            def organisationInstance= OrganisationShr.findByName(secUserInstance.organId)
        returnValue = 20 //organisationInstance.id
    }


    log.debug(" $tagName returnValue: $returnValue")
    //return returnValue
    out << body(returnValue)
} // end returnLoginInfo
```

This code in your view works:

```
<g:returnLoginInfo loginId="${loginId}" fieldName="organId">
    <g:set var="organId" value="${it}" />
</g:returnLoginInfo>
<h3>As taglib: organId = ${organId}</h3>

<g:returnLoginInfo loginId="${loginId}" fieldName="notOrganId">
    <g:set var="organId" value="${it}" />
</g:returnLoginInfo>
<h3>As taglib: organId = ${organId}</h3>
```

Providing me the output 20 and 10 for organId.

When that is said, I'm not sure I would use a TagLib for your usecase, I would use a service, and provide the value through the map given to the view by the controller.

UPDATE 2:

The above is verified with Grails 2.5.0. Your usecase does not seam like a TagLib usecase, when all you wan't is to set a value. I would go in a different direction. If you don't need parameters (as they might come from  the session or a security service), filters would do the job.

The Service for the logic could be like this:

```
@Transactional
class DemoService {

  List<Integer> myServiceMethod(Integer i) {
    if( i > 0) {
        (1..i).collect { it }
    } else {
        [i]
    }
  }
}
```

and you could do a filter like this:

```
class MyFilterFilters {

  DemoService demoService

  def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {

        }
        after = { Map model ->
            model.myIdValue = demoService.myServiceMethod(5)

        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->

        }
    }
  }
}
```

And you have access to myIdValue directly in every view:

```
<p> ${myIdValue}</p>
```

If you need parameters, you can use a service directly from a view (not recommended - but possible, and no more performance hit than using it from a taglib):

```
<p> ${grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("demoService").myServiceMethod(3)}</p>
```

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions. But have not been able to pass the value into organId. I've edited the original post adding a listing of the tagLib and displaying the two ways you've suggested to call it from the view. I'm not sure that I'm implementing your suggestions correctly - perhaps you can elaborate?

Comment: When you have defined your taglib like that, where you have 2 arguments to the closure, and call the body as a method, only the second way is useable. I've just tried it (commenting out the things I don't have access to) and it works. See the answer for the updated code.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with your suggestions - perhaps it's a version of grails issue? I also explored the scope option in the g:set again to no avail. For application specific reasons I need to keep grails at version 2.3.3 at this stage.The reason I specifically want to use a tagLib is that this is being invoked from a _header file which appears in all views - so replacing with a service would mean I would need to pass the data from the tagLib (organId) I need to display though every action - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to implement your suggestions of employing a service . But I get an error  `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - 
Error initializing the application: Method on class [homevu1.HvFilters] was used outside of a Grails application. ` - where HvFilters is the filter for the service. Looking through some other posts without finding any solutions - perhaps you can suggests what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the Filter in the controller folder? It should be to be decorated with the right Grails magic

Comment: See original post above for code a update. I've got passed the GrailsContextLoader issue and I'm now getting an app to run and test. A change to the filter declaration solved that - I placed the filter class in the domain folder but moved it to the controller folder as suggested. I don't think it made any difference However, tried invoking this filter in two ways but I'm unable to get output either from the filter or directly from the service into the web page. It seems that the web page is unable to resolve the filter/service name into the filter/service.

Comment: I have managed to get the running of the service via a bean working - replace the upper case H to a lower case in the service name: "hvLoginDetailsService" getBean call as spring always resolves classes to lower case. But still cannot get the filter working in the web page.

Comment: I'm satisfied that this problem has been resolved now calling the service directly from the view:  ` <g:set var="organId" value="${grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("hvLoginDetailsService").myLoginDetails("organisation")}" /> ` . The advantage being that I can pass input parameters to the service.

Comment: Perfect! Filters should work automatically, so I don't understand the "tried invoking this filter in two ways" but that is another story. You found a solution and that is key :)